# gettext translation in PHP works fine, but not with javascript

Tags: javascript, multilingual, gettext, translate

I use gettext in combination with *.po and *.mo files to translate my little website into  different languages. User can chose on a dropdown their preferred language, the site gets refreshed and the chosen language is shown.

When it comes to translate javascript content that appears when user interacts (for example: a note to type minimum 6 characters below the input field) I dont know how to solve it properly. Is there an easy way how to get that notes also with gettext like in php translated? I read here a lot about it and tried what I could, but somehow I cant figure it out.

**Here is the simplified index.js code:**

```
let messageUserText;
let userInput;

messageUserText     = document.getElementById('userMsg');
userInput           = document.getElementById('usernameInput');

function validInput() {
    const userName      = usernameInput.value;

    let messageUserName = '';

    if (userName === '') {
        messageUserName = 'Please enter username';
    } else if (userName.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9üÜöÖäÄ]/) === -1) {
        messageUserName = 'Username accepted';
    } else {
        messageUserName = 'Please check username';
    }
    messageUserText.innerHTML = messageUserName;
}
```

**This is the simplified code in index.php:**

```
<?php
   require_once("locale.php");
   include_once('header.php');
?>
...
<!-- DROPDOWN LANGUAGE SELECTION -->
        <form name="locale" action="index.php" method="POST">
              <button type="button" class="dropdown">
                      <!-- SHOW CHOSEN LANGUAGE -->
                      <?php 
                        if (isset($_POST['locbtn'])) {
                          if ($_POST['locbtn'] === 'en_EN') {
                            echo "EN";
                          } else if ($_POST['locbtn'] === 'de_DE') {
                            echo "DE";
                          }
                        }
                        else {
                          echo "EN";
                        }?>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><button class="item" type="submit" value="en_EN" name="locbtn"><?php echo _("DE"); ?></button></li>
                <li><button class="item" type="submit" value="de_DE" name="locbtn"><?php echo _("EN"); ?></button></li>
              </ul>
            </form>
   ...
          <!-- INPUT FORM -->
          <div>
            <form>
              <!-- Floating Labels INPUT USER -->
                  <input type="text" 
                     placeholder="<?php echo _("Username"); ?>" 
                     aria-label="<?php echo _("Username"); ?>" 
                     id="usernameInput" 
                     onkeyup="validInput()" 
                   required>
                  <label for="usernameInput">
                     <?php echo _(" Username"); ?>
                  </label>  
              <!-- NOTE MESSAGE: THIS IS WHERE I CANT TRANSLATE APPEARING JAVASCRIPT CONTENT-->
               <p id="userMsg"></p>
    ...
    <!-- Javascripts-->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/index.js"></script>

    <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

**This is the locale.php**

```
    <?php
        //Locale Main & HTML Handler
        if (isset($_POST['locbtn'])) {
            
            $locale = $_POST['locbtn'];
                      
            if ($_POST['locbtn'] === 'en_EN') {
                $htmlLanguage = 'en';
            } else if ($_POST['locbtn'] === 'de_DE') {
                $htmlLanguage = 'de';
            }
        } else {
            $htmlLanguage = 'en';
            $locale = 'en_EN';
        }

       // Set lang env
       putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");

       // Set locale:
       setlocale( LC_MESSAGES, $locale);

       // Name of translation files
       $domain = 'test';

       // Set the path for a domain
       $pathToDomain = "/home/locale/";
       bindtextdomain($domain, $pathToDomain);

       // Set codeset
       bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

       textdomain($domain);
    ?>
```

Comment: You can research `fetch API` that will allow you to send the input to the PHP and have it return the translated text back. Or if the messages are static, just load them in a javascript object on page load and access that data as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, maybe you have further explanations with sample code, I know its late but I cant really understand what you mean :)) The message changes, depending what the user is typing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example using an object to create a key/value pair of the translations per language.

```js
let selected_lang = "en"; //use cookies, localstorage or even php to hardcode the language that they previously selected

let translations = {};

translations["en"] = {
 "username-empty" : "Please enter username",
 "username-valid" : "Username accepted",
 "username-unknown" : "Please check username"
};

translations["de"] = {
 "username-empty" : "GERMAN Please enter username",
 "username-valid" : "GERMAN Username accepted",
 "username-unknown" : "GERMAN Please check username"
};

function getTranslation(field){
    return translations[selected_lang][field];
}

function validInput() {
    const userName      = usernameInput.value;

    let messageUserName = '';

    if (userName === '') {
        messageUserName = getTranslation("username-empty");
    } else if (userName.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9üÜöÖäÄ]/) === -1) {
        messageUserName = getTranslation("username-valid");
    } else {
        messageUserName = getTranslation("username-unknown");
    }
    messageUserText.innerHTML = messageUserName;
}

console.log(getTranslation("username-unknown"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, in the meanwhile I was able to solve it. I pass the affected variables (which contains the translated strings using gettext) to the function in the javascript code. Just had some syntax problems in the beginning, but now everything works fine. Thanks!!